# Dictionary from CSV

Tags: python

I work with data from spreadsheets a lot, and I typically start working with a function like this on that converts it into a dictionary of dictionaries:

```
def get_terms():
    terms = {}
    with open('Terms.csv') as infile:
        reader = csv.reader(infile, dialect='excel')
        headers = next(reader)
        for line in reader:
            term_id = line[0]
            terms[term_id] = {}
            for i, val in enumerate(line):
                terms[term_id][headers[i]] = val
    return terms
```

Since I use this so often, I was just wondering if there is an easier way... What do you think?

Answer (score 1):

If you're frequently working with tabular data, I'd recommend switching over to `pandas`, a library that makes it easier to do a lot of the typical manipulations you'd do on tables:
http://pandas.pydata.org/

Reading a CSV with it is just `pd.read_csv('file.csv')`.

Comment: I've used pandas before; for example I used it to write this (bad) script to create daily pivot tables for our entering students at my school: https://github.com/BenQuigley/check-in-counts-report

I have found it pretty tough to use so far. I feel like a lot of the things I've learned how to do in Python, I've had to relearn how to do differently in pandas. I guess I'll keep at it. Any feedback would be welcome.

Answer (score 1):

You can do this simply using pandas library

```
import pandas
data = pandas.read_csv('Terms.csv')
data.to_dict()
```

Comment: Seems to take a bit longer unfortunately, though maybe it scales just as well.

Comment: pandas is bit heavy library to load initially...but it will be really helpful if u planning to lot of tabular manipulation